# Add Multiple Products To Cart at Once in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-subscriptions

In bundle like select any of 3 products with subscription

And not like T-shirt size color

Use case - hair gel three different types of hair

Hair lotion - three different types of lotion

Shaving gel - three different varity

They are all different products

Like in india we get shampoo

Now with subscription user needs to select any three products

Out of 9 variation products

Comment: This might be of some assistance https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/group-bundle-products-woocommerce/

Comment: "Select any three" would be [Mix and Match](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-mix-and-match-products) by yours truly. It does work with Subscriptions and [Subscribe all the Things](https://github.com/Prospress/woocommerce-subscribe-all-the-things)